# How do I attach a debugger to a Java program running with Commons Daemon Service Runner?

Tags: java, debugging, apache-commons, jdb

I would like to do some debugging on a Java program running on Windows: backtrace, print some variables, set breakpoints, single-step through a critical function.

The first thing I tried was `jdb -attach 5312`. This failed with "shmemBase_attach failed: The system cannot find the file specified". I found some [related](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4220174/2404501) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5380118/2404501) about that error message but they seem to be talking about a more complex scenario involving debugger and target on separate hosts.

What I'm doing is a local process attach, so I think it should be easier. But there is something making it harder.

The target process isn't run as `java -jar foo.jar` or anything normal like that. It's an application-specific EXE file wrapping the java code. It identifies itself in a process listing as "Commons Daemon Service Runner" and looking at the strings inside it, it seems to be [the `prunsrv` program from Apache Commons Daemon](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-daemon/procrun.html).

Process Explorer tells me that there are no command line arguments, and the process is a child of services.exe. I have the ability to start and stop it from Windows Services, but I don't know how to do anything else with it.

The `jps` command doesn't show this process, but I know that it is a Java program... lightly wrapped. Is there any way to debug it?

Answer (score 0):

Try to set _JAVA_OPTIONS variable to something like this:

`_JAVA_OPTIONS "-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=32887"`

This variable should be picked up by JVM while it is started.

Then, you can try to attach to this JVM by calling

`jdb -attach 32887`

where 32887 is an arbitrary port number used by debugger (numbers have to match).

**Update:**

You can use different means of connection. It's up to you. What I have given you is just one example of many, different, ways of settings things up. Take a look here for more details:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jpda/conninv.html

You can also use VisualVM. In that case you need to have JVM process visible to user that is running VisualVM.

Comment: I have to alter the way the program is run to make it debuggable? And I have to use a remote debugging protocol to debug a local process? This seems very strange to me, being used to gdb on unix where I can attach to any process by PID, without needing any cooperation from it (if I am the owner or root). I will try it out...

Comment: And it accepts remote connections from everyone, with [no authentication whatsoever](http://blog.ioactive.com/2014/04/hacking-java-debug-wire-protocol-or-how.html)! That's not usable.

Comment: After looking at several options, I found this combination: `jdb -connector com.sun.jdi.SocketListen:port=12345` and then configure the target service using `prunmgr`, and add the option `-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=127.0.0.1:12345,server=n,suspend=y`. I figure it's slightly less stupid to give the world unauthenticated access to attach to my debugger as a debuggee than the other way around. Still amazed that there's no simple `PTRACE_ATTACH`-style interface.

Comment: `jdb -attach` doesn't work on Windows if the debugee is listening on a port.